# Probability distribution of order statistics

Tags: probability-distributions

> Let $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ be independent  random variable with continuous distribution $$f(x;\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta}I_{(0,\theta]}(x), \ \theta \gt 0$$
>   I need to find distribution of $Z=\frac{X_{(3)}}{\theta}$, where $X_{(3)}=\max\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$

I read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329995/procedure-for-max-function-with-identical-random-variables). I would start with the cumulative distribution function of $f(x;\theta)$

$$F(x;\theta)= \left \{
    \begin{array}{cl}
        \int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{\theta}dv = \frac{x}{\theta}& 0 \lt x \leq \theta \\
        0 & \text{Otherwise}
    \end{array}
\right .$$

Now, $\mathbb{P}(\max\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}\leq z)=\mathbb{P}((X_1,X_2,X_3)\leq z)$. They are independent thus $\mathbb{P}((X_1,X_2,X_3)\leq z)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq z)\mathbb{P}(X_2\leq z)\mathbb{P}(X_3\leq z)=(F(z;\theta))^3=(\frac{z}{\theta})^3$

Am I close to solution? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to a solution. Let $W=\max(X_1,X_2,X_3)$. You found that
$$F_W(w)=\frac{w^3}{\theta^3}$$
(for $0\lt w\lt \theta$). I changed letters a little because $z$ might cause confusion with the random variable $Z$, which is $\frac{W}{\theta}$.

Ultimately you want to find $E(Z)$, which is $\frac{1}{\theta}E(W)$. So let us find $E(W)$.

You know the cdf of $W$, so by differentiating you can find the density function of $W$, and then find $E(W)$ in the usual way.

*Remark:* It is maybe marginally easier to note that $Z\le z$ if and only if all the $X_i$ are $\le \theta z$, which has probability $z^3$. Now find the density of $Z$ by differentiating, and calculate the mean as usual.

Comment: I think this is correct: The density function is $f(w;\theta)=\frac{dF}{dw}=\frac{3}{\theta^3}w^2$, the expectation is $\mathbb{E}(W)=\int_0^\theta (\frac{3}{\theta^3}w^2w)\,dw=\int_0^\theta (\frac{3}{\theta^3}w^3)\,dw=\frac{3}{4}\theta$ and then
$\mathbb{E}(Z)=\frac{1}{\theta}\mathbb{E}(W)=\frac{3}{4}$

Comment: Yes, the answer is indeed $3/4$.