# Let $N_n$ be the number of throws before all $n$ dice have shown $6$. Set $m_n := E[N_n]$. Write a recursive formula for $m_n$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose we throw $n$ independent dices. After each throw we put aside the dices
showing $6$ and then perform a new throw with the dices not showing $6$, repeating the process until all dices have shown $6$. Let $N_n$ be the number of throws before all dice have shown $6$. Set $m_n := E[N_n]$ and let $Y$ denote the number of dices not showing $6$ after the first throw.

I've showed that $Y \sim b(n,\frac 5 6)$, because we can consider the throw as $n$ independent trials with succes probability $\frac 5 6$.

Now I must write a recursive formula for $m_n$ and decide $m_1, \ldots, m_5$.

Using the definition of expectation of a discrete RV:

$E[N_n] = 1 \cdot P(N_n = 1) + 2 \cdot P(N_n = 2) + \ldots$

But this is not very recursive - Any suggestions ?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26167/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-iid-geometric-random-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$m_{n}=\mathbb{E}N_{n}=\sum_{y=0}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left(N_{n}\mid Y=y\right)P\left(Y=y\right)$$
Here $\mathbb{E}\left(N_{n}\mid Y=y\right)=m_{y}+1$, $m_{0}=0$ and
applying the distribution of $Y$ this gives: $$m_{n}=\sum_{y=0}^{n}\left(m_{y}+1\right)\binom{n}{y}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{y}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{n-y}$$

and leads to:$$m_{n}=\sum_{y=0}^{n}m_{y}\binom{n}{y}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{y}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{n-y}+1=\sum_{y=1}^{n-1}m_{y}\binom{n}{y}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{y}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{n-y}+m_{n}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n}+1$$

resulting in: $$m_{n}=\frac{6^{n}+\sum_{y=1}^{n-1}m_{y}\binom{n}{y}5^{y}}{6^{n}-5^{n}}$$

---

**addendum** (in order to say something about the distribution of $N_n$)

Give the dice the numbers $1,2,\dots,n$ and let $D_{i}$ denote the
number of throws that are needed for the die with number $i$ to produce
a $6$.

Note that $N_{n}\leq k$ if and only if $D_{i}\leq k$ for
$i=1,\dots,n$. That means that: $$P\left(N_{n}\leq k\right)=P\left(D_{1}\leq k\right)\times\cdots\times P\left(D_{n}\leq k\right)$$
Here $P\left(D_{i}\leq k\right)=1-P\left(D_{i}>k\right)=1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{k}$
for every $i$  leading to: $$P\left(N_{n}\leq k\right)=\left(1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{k}\right)^{n}$$
In one of my comments I stated that it would be 'quite a job to find
the distribution of $N_{n}$' but I was wrong there. In fact Did  made
use of this on a very elegant way in his answer. In general if $X$ is an rv taking values on positive
integers then: $$\mathbb{E}X=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P\left(X>k\right)$$
Applying that here leads to: $$\mathbb{E}N_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P\left(N_{n}>k\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left[1-\left(1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{k}\right)^{n}\right]$$

Comment: Amazing @drhab. However can you clarify why this is true ? $$m_{n}=\mathbb{E}N_{n}=\sum_{y=0}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left(N_{n}\mid Y=y\right)P\left(Y=y\right)$$ - the last equality.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are rv's with a common distribution and $Y$ only
takes values in a countable set $C$ then $\mathbb{E}X=\sum_{c\in C}\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid Y=c\right)P\left(Y=c\right)$
where $\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid Y=c\right)$ denotes the expectation
of $X$ under condition $Y=c$. This falls under the 'chapter' of
conditional expectation. Explaining it here goes too far, but there
are lots of places where you can find more information about this
issue. Start for instance at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation.

Comment: Thanks so much @drhab. Btw, how could one find the common distribution function of $X,Y$ with the information given here ? Another question: How does one prove $E(N_n \mid Y = y) = 1 + m_y$ without using "intuition" only ?

Comment: In general common distribution of $X$ and $Y$ cannot be determined on base of this information. In the case mentioned in your question it will be quite a job to find the distribution of $N_n$ and it becomes even more complicated if you go for the common distribution of $N_n$ and $Y$. Be satisfied by $EN_n$ I would say. Set $N_{n}=1+M_{n}$ where $M_{n}$ denotes the number of throws taking
place after the first. Under condition $Y=y$ we have the original situation with $y$ dice to be thrown. Under this condition $M_{n}$ and $N_{y}$ must have the same distribution. Then $EN_{n}=1+EM_{n}=1+m_{y}$.

Comment: Thank once again @drhab your answer and comments really clarified things for me.

Comment: Don't you miss $y = 0$ in your sum formula ? You start from index $1$ ?

Comment: I could do that because $m_0=0$ as was mentioned.

Comment: Yes but you still have $1 \cdot (1/6)^n$ corresponding to $y = 0$  then ?

Comment: I get the formula, calculated by hand, $$m_n = \frac {\sum^{n-1}_{y=0} (m_y + 1) \binom {n} {y} 5^y} {6^n - 5^n}$$

Comment: You were right about missing the case $y=0$ after all. I repaired and added. The recursion expression is not changed however. Have a look. Also note that it gives $m_1=6$ as it should (geometric distribution).

Comment: "And this leads to:" - Now $m_n$ should be replaced by $(m_n + 1)$ ? You are not multiplying $1$ by the factors ?

Comment: Ahh, thanks. Is my formula also correct in the comment above ?

Comment: $\sum_{y=0}^{n}\binom{n}{y}(\frac{5}{6})^{y}(\frac{1}{6})^{n-y}=1$. Your formula is not correcie because for the term $\binom{n}{y}5^{y}$ there must be a summation from $0$ to $n$ (not to $n-1$)

Comment: Yours gives for instance $m_1=0$ which is not correct.

Comment: Ahh I know get $$m_n= \frac {(\sum^{n−1}_{y=0}(m_y+1)\binom n y 5^y) + 5^n}  {6^n−5^n}$$

Comment: and notice that $\sum_{y=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{y}5^{y}=\sum_{y=0}^{n}\binom{n}{y}5^{y}-5^{n}=6^{n}-5^{n}$ leading exactly to my formula!

Comment: May I ask how I could find the distribution for $N_n$ ? How can I verify that $P(N_n \le \infty) = 1$ ? I've tried to write $P(N_n \le k)$ for some small $k \in \mathbb N$ - again, how can I see that this sum equals $1$ ? (I'm curious).

Comment: I have added something. The answer of @Did was very inspiring.

Answer (score 3):

Two closed formulas, not based on the recursion you suggest:
$$
E(N_n)=\sum_{k\geqslant0}\left(1-\left(1-\left(\frac56\right)^k\right)^n\right)
$$
$$
E(N_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n{n\choose i}\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{1-\left(\frac56\right)^i}
$$

Comment: How did you do that? You made me curious and some link will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @drhab The dice are independent and each produces a six at time $k$ or before, with probability $1-(5/6)^k$, hence the $k$th term of the first formula above is $P(N_n\gt k)$. To deduce the second formula, expand each binomial $(1-(5/6)^k)^n$ into powers of $5/6$ and interchange the order of the summations in the double sum this yields.

Comment: I see (tibi gratias ago). It encourages me to investigate earlyer whether the relation between $E(X)$ and probabilities $P(X\geq n)$ can be expoited. It never crossed my mind in this situation. Big focus on recurrence off course, but that is not an excuse.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the first throw. Given that we get no six, the expectation is $1+m_{n}$. Given that we get exactly $1$ six, the expectation is $1+m_{n-1}$. Given that we get $2$ sixes, the expectation is $1+m_{n-2}$, and so on. Thus
$$m_n=\sum_{k=0}^n (1+m_{n-k})\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{k}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-k} .$$
We can simplify this a bit, by solving for $m_n$, and combining the "$1$" terms. There may be further simplification.

**Remark:** We assumed that for example the first throw of the $n$ dice counts as $1$ throw. If throwing $k$ dice counts as $k$ throws, then the problem is simpler.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, but I had intended $(1/6)^k(5/6)^{n-k}$, so I have altered that part instead of the "$m$" part.

Comment: Thank you @André Nicolas. However "Consider the first throw. Given that we get no six, the expectation is $1+m_n$. Given that we get exactly 1 six, the expectation is $1+m_{n−1}$.", how do I show this is true in terms of the expectation definition and not just intuitively ?

Comment: To be more specific how does one prove equality between your formula and $E[N_n] = 1 \cdot P(N_n = 1) + 2 \cdot P(N_n = 2) + \ldots$ ?

Comment: As you can see, we are giving a conditional expectation argument, $E(N_n)=E((N_n|Y))$. I think the intuitive calculation of $E(N_n|Y=k)$ is enough. We throw the dice. If we get $k$ sixes, we have used up a throw, and the additional expectation is by definition $n_{n-k}$.

Comment: Can one prove $E(N_n) = E((N_n) \mid Y))$ or is this also intuition ? What is this rule called ?

Comment: It even has a name, the Law of Total Expectation (see, e.g., Wikipedia, or many probability books.) Except that I did not type enough $E$'s above, it is $E(E(N_n|Y))$.

Comment: Also your formula is circular $m_n$ is defined in terms of $m_n$ ?

Comment: Sort of. That's why I mentioned solving for $m_n$. Bring the $k=0$ term to the left side. We get $\left(1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n\right)m_n=\sum_{k=1}^n(\text{the stuff})$.