# Name the problem: Numbers of dice throws to get result with rerolls allowed

Tags: probability-distributions, terminology, dice

Here is the problem:

- You have `N` dice of size `D`. You throw all dices, then for each dice:

  - if a dice face is `d` in `D` leave it like that
  - otherwise re-roll the dice, until you get `d`
- What is the expected *probability distribution* (is this a correct term?) for a total number of individual dice throws to get `d` on all dices ?

My question is:

- **Is there a name for such problem ?** Or a name of a branch of probability theory to deal with this ?

Similar question: 
[Let $N_n$ be the number of throws before all $n$ dice have shown $6$. Set $m_n := E[N_n]$. Write a recursive formula for $m_n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748235/let-n-n-be-the-number-of-throws-before-all-n-dice-have-shown-6-set-m-n) has answers, but does not explain what are we searching for.

Comment: This is kind of "jeopardy" question ("guess the question given answer"), but I really don't have the mathematical education to formulate it on my own, and intuition tells that this should be something that students study on their first or second year.

Comment: I am not sure you would expect this question to be in a class which has a name, but the approaches are similar to those you would use where the underlying distributions were geometric or negative binomial or binomial, so discrete distributions on non-negative integers.  For example, the CDF (i,e, the probability of needing $n$ or fewer throws) is $\left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{D}\right)^{n}\right)^{N}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- all dice are the same (and independent), so calculate for 1, then multiply by N
- all faces are equal (that’s a definition of a die, right?), so d=1

So a simplified problem is: “number of rolls until getting 1 on it”. Which is a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with $p=1/D$

> The probability distribution of the number X of Bernoulli trials needed to get one success, supported on the set { 1, 2, 3, ...}