# Expected number of days of watching movie

Tags: probability, expectation

Let us suppose I have a list of $n$ movies and each day I chose a subset of this movies where the probability of choosing any movie from the list is p . Now , what would be the expected number of days it would take to watch all of the $n$ movies ? A movie can watched again on another day but we want the day when we have at least watched each movie once .

Comment: You choose a *subset* of movies, yet only the probability of choosing *a movie* is mentioned. Is the subset of fixed size (for all days)?

Comment: The probability is independent , that is the probability of choosing any three movies would be $p^3$ .

Comment: I interpreted it as the probability you'll include the movie is p

Comment: You cannot give an discrete answer like   "*after x days all movies have been watched*", only "*after x days the **probability** that all movies have been watched is...*"

Comment: I think he means the number of days so that with more than 50% likelihood all movies have been watched.

Comment: What I mean is the expected number of days I have to choose and watch movies such that all are watched .

Comment: He is asking you what you mean by "expected number of days".

Comment: Ok , I mean is what is the probability all movies have been watched after x days . Is it clear now ?

Comment: The probability and the expectation are different prob;ems.

Comment: If I know the probability for x days would not the expectation be x*p(x) ?

Comment: The best thing to use is the linearity of expectation.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation or answer on how to apply linearity of expectation , as I have tried to apply it but no success so far .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a variation of the [coupon collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) problem, but I don't see a way to use its elegant method here.

Let $a_{t}$ be the probability that after day $t$ , all movies have been seen ($t=0,1 \cdots$). Let $q=1-p$

Then $$a_{t}= (1-q^t)^n$$

Let $T$ be the amount of days it took to see al movies. Then

$$P(T \ge t)=1-a_{t-1}=1-(1-q^{t-1})^n$$

But $$E(T)=\sum_{t=1} P(T \ge t)=\sum_{u=0} 1- (1-q^u)^n  $$

And

$$ 1- (1-q^u)^n =1  - \sum_{j=0}^n {n \choose j} (-1)^j q^{ju}=\sum_{j=1}^n {n \choose j} (-1)^{j+1} q^{ju}$$

$$E(T) = \sum_{j=1}^n {n \choose j} (-1)^{j+1} \sum_{u=0} q^{ju} = \sum_{j=1}^n {n \choose j} (-1)^{j+1}  \frac{1}{1-q^j}$$

I wonder if this can simplified

Added: I think that this is basically equivalent to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26167/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-iid-geometric-random-variables)