# LCM of randomly selected integers

Tags: number-theory, random

What is the expected LCM of 21 randomly selected positive integers under 10000000?

How would someone even approach this problem?

**EDIT:** The positive integers are chosen with replacement.

Comment: I would approach it by seeing what happens with smaller numbers, in particular, what's the expected LCM for **two** random integers (less than whatever).  Also, are you selecting random integers *with* or *without* replacement?  I.e., can you select the same number more than once?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of that. By the way, you can select the same number more than once.

Comment: If  $P(n$) is the chance that 2 random numbers less than $ n$ (with replacement) are co-prime then $ \lim_{n \to \infty} P(n)=6 \pi^{-2}$.

Comment: What kind of answer do you want? Exact number? Algorithm to determine it? Asymptotic size as 10000000 goes to infinity?

Answer (score 1):

Let $1 \leq a_1, \dots, a_n \leq N$ be number chosen uniformly at random.  What is their [least common multiple](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6yHKOYJiso)?

What is the highest power of $2$ dividing any of the $a_1, \dots, a_n$?

- All the numbers are odd with probability $(1 - \frac{1}{2})^n$
- All the numbers are odd or even (but not divisible by **4**) with probability $(1 - \frac{1}{4})^n$
- All the numbers are odd or even (but not divisible by **8**) with probability $(1 - \frac{1}{8})^n$
- ...

So the expected power of $2$ dividing all these numbers is (this number might simplify):

$$ \mathbb{E}_2 = \sum_{k \geq 0} \Big(2^k - 2^{k-1} \Big) \left[1- \left( 1- \tfrac{1}{2^k} \right)^n \right]$$

A similar story for $\mathbb{E}_3, \mathbb{E}_5, \mathbb{E}_7$ etc; multiply your answers

$$ \mathbb{E} = \prod_{p } \mathbb{E}_p$$

---

See also: [Expectation of the maximum of i.i.d. geometric random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26167/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-iid-geometric-random-variables) **a quick look confirms there is no closed-form answer**.

In your case $n = 21$ and $N = 1,000,000$ so we can hope for an estimate.

---

One way to state the prime number theorem is that $\mathrm{lcm}(1,2,\dots, n) = e^n$ So the least common multiple is growing exponentially fast in $n$.  In your case, there are $n = 21$ numbers ranging from $1$ to $N = 10^6$.  Perhaps

$$ \mathbb{E} \approx e^{n} \times \left(\frac{N}{n}\right)^n \approx \frac{N^n}{n!} = \frac{10^{21}}{ 21!} \approx \frac{10^{21}}{ 5 \times 10^{19}} = 40 $$

Still doesn't seem quite right.  See Granville [Prime Number Races](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408319))

Comment: $N^n$ is $(10^6)^21$, not $10^21$. This would lead to $2⋅10^{104}$.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you chose the integer with replacement or not is unlikely to make a difference: the probability to have 21 different integers in your set of 21 is
$$\exp\left(\sum_{i=0}^{20}\log\left(1-\frac i{10^7}\right) \right)\simeq 1 - \frac{20⋅21}{2⋅10^7}=1-2.1⋅10^{-5}$$.

A paper by Cilleruelo, Rué, Šarka and Zumalacárregui ([arXiv:1112.3013](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.3013) , [J. Num. Th. **144** 92](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2014.04.011)) specifically addresses similar questions. They compute $\DeclareMathOperator\lcm{lcm}$ 
$$ψ(A)=\log\lcm\{a:a∈A\} $$ for random subsets $A⊆\{1…n\}$ of size $|A|=k(n)$ when $n→∞$. When $k(n)→∞$, their theorem 1.2 says that, almost surely 
$$ψ(A)=k\frac{\log\frac nk}{1-\frac kn}\left(1+O\left(e^{-C\sqrt{\log k}}\right)\right), $$
for a constant $C$.

In your case, you have $n=10^7$, $k=21$. Since $k$ is not really large, you should look into the paper to see how this is proven, and to which extent it applies to your case. Boldly assuming $k=21→∞$ (I know !), would led to

$$ψ(A)=21\frac{19.16}{1-2.1⋅10^{-6}}\left(1+O\left(e^{-1.74C}\right)\right) ∼ 400 \text{, if $C$ is big enough.} $$

In other words, we would have $\lcm(A)∼e^{400}∼5⋅10^{173}$ if my rough unjustified approximations are correct.