# You are flipping n fair coins, putting aside those that come up heads after each flip. What's the expected number of rounds?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This question is related to https://www.quora.com/You-are-flipping-100-coins-putting-aside-those-that-come-up-heads-after-each-flip-How-many-flips-do-you-expect-to-make-before-running-out-of-coins-to-flip

At each stage, you flip all your coins and only keep the ones that are tail. You stop when you ran out of coins. Some Quora answers mention that the expected number of rounds is logarithmic with respect to $n$. Any suggestions on how you would prove this fact?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expectation of the maximum of i.i.d. geometric random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26167/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-i-i-d-geometric-random-variables)

Comment: How are the two problems the same?

Comment: Let $X_i$ be the number of rounds the $i^{th}$ coin survives for. The $X_i$ are i.i.d. geometric, and you want the maximum of the $X_i$.