# Nonlinear Transformations of Standard Normal iid Random Variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, change-of-variable

I'm having a rather difficult time with these types of problems.

Say we are are considering two random variables $X_1$, $X_2$ ~ $N(0,1)$.

We want to compute the distribution of $U=\frac{X_1}{X_1 + X_2}$.

My first attempts at this sought to use the the joint density of $U$, $V=X_2$ and then compute the marginal density. This brings us to a seemingly unsolvable integral. Is there some way to compute this without performing a wildly difficult gaussian integral?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [X,Y are independent standard normal distributed then what is the distribution of $\frac{X}{X+Y}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89870/x-y-are-independent-standard-normal-distributed-then-what-is-the-distribution-of)

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- $U=\frac{1}{1 + Y}$ where $Y=\frac{X_2}{X_1}$
- Consider the distribution of $\frac1U$
- If $X_1,X_2$ i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ then $\frac{X_2}{X_1} \sim \operatorname{Cauchy}(0,1)$
- If $Z \sim \operatorname{Cauchy}(x_0,\gamma)$ then $\frac1Z \sim \operatorname{Cauchy}\left(\frac{x_0}{x_0^2+\gamma^2},\frac{\gamma}{x_0^2+\gamma^2}\right)$

Comment: Ah, this really makes sense. Would distribution of 1+Y just be a Cauchy(1,1)? I'm trying  to make an analogy from what I would expect of the normal distribution, but the Cauchy distribution doesn't actually have a mean.

Comment: No, wait... That would just be exactly the same distribution, wouldn't it? Since the support set is all real numbers, the addition of any one number doesn't affect the distribution at all.

Comment: Okay, now I'm like 100% certain that it's X+1~Cauchy(-1,1) given that X~Cauchy(0,1). All of this finally makes sense now. Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: @Algebraic: $Y=\frac{X_2}{X_1}\sim \operatorname{Cauchy}(0,1)$ so $1+Y \sim \operatorname{Cauchy}(1,1)$.  You want $\frac{1}{1+Y}$

Comment: Are you sure about that? I did the transformation and found the median to be int_{-infinity}^{-1}. Of course, I understood to introduce the transformations one at a time, then use the inverse property of the Cauchy distribution.

Comment: @Algebraic The median of $Y=\frac{X_2}{X_1}$ is $0$, the median of $1+Y=\frac{X_1+X_2}{X_1}$ is $1$, and the median of $\frac1{1+Y}=\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}$ is $\frac12$, and simulation will confirm this