# E[X+Y | X-Y] for exponentially distributed variables.

Tags: probability

I've been stuck with a more or less simple task for a while now, and I would appreciate any help you can give me.

So I have $X \sim exp(\lambda)$, $Y \sim exp(\lambda)$ and I have to find $E(X+Y | X-Y)$.

I know it has to look something like this:

$$\int_o^{\infty} (x+y) f(x+y | X-Y) dxdy, $$

and from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115022/pdf-of-the-difference-of-two-exponentially-distributed-random-variables) I know the distribution of the difference, but somehow I still fail to put all of those together. Any tips will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach is to first determine the density $f$ of the distribution of 
$$(S,T)=(X+Y,X-Y).
$$
The change of variable $(x,y)\to(s,t)=(x+y,x-y)$ on the domain $x\gt0$ and $y\gt0$ has Jacobian $2$ and is one-to-one to the domain $|t|\lt s$ hence the identity
$$
\lambda\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}\lambda\mathrm e^{-\lambda y}\mathbf 1_{x\gt0,y\gt0}=\lambda^2\mathrm e^{-\lambda s}\mathbf 1_{|t|\lt s},
$$
implies that
$$
f(s,t)=\tfrac12\lambda^2\mathrm e^{-\lambda s}\mathbf 1_{|t|\lt s}.
$$
Next, the density $g$ of $T$ is
$$
g(t)=\int f(s,t)\mathrm ds=\tfrac12\lambda\int_{|t|}^\infty\lambda\mathrm e^{-\lambda s}\mathrm ds=\tfrac12\lambda\mathrm e^{-\lambda |t|},
$$
hence the conditional density $h_t$ of $S$ conditionally on $T=t$ is
$$
h_t(s)=\frac{f(s,t)}{g(t)}=\lambda\mathrm e^{-\lambda (s- |t|)}\mathbf 1_{s\gt|t|}.
$$
In other words, $S=|T|+R$ where $R$ is exponential with parameter $\lambda$ and independent of $T$, hence
$$
E(X+Y|X-Y)=E(S|T)=|T|+E(R)=|X-Y|+\lambda^{-1}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I got most of the densities you wrote but couldn't figure out how to write one big integral. Apparently, it's possible to not write it down explicitly.