# Question about exp. distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

We know that $X\sim \exp(1),Y\sim \exp(2)$ and they are independent.
What is $P(Y>X)$?
exp=Exponential...

Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately this is ambiguous.  Sometimes $\mathrm{Exp}(2)$ means an exponential distribution with expected value $2$, so that $\Pr(Y>y) = e^{-y/2}$ for $y\ge0$, and sometimes it means the _rate_ is $2$, so that $\Pr(Y>y)=e^{-2y}$ for $y\ge0$ (and then the expected value would be $1/2$). ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I suspect that the reason someone down-voted this question is that you haven't included any thoughts on how to answer it.

Comment: I edit it, now it's clear?

Comment: No, it's not.  Either way, it's an exponential distribution.

Comment: So did you mean the expected value is $2$?

Comment: $f_X(X)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x>0$ @MichaelHardy

Comment: This may help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115022/pdf-of-the-difference-of-two-exponentially-distributed-random-variables

Comment: It don't :-( @user159813, I'm confused from this...

Comment: If you know pdf, of Y-X, than you can find answer of P(Y>X)=P(Y-X>0) and this may help

Comment: @user159813, can you help me with the final answer please? I think that I need more hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this previous question([pdf of the difference of two exponentially distributed random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115022/pdf-of-the-difference-of-two-exponentially-distributed-random-variables)) they derive for $Y\sim Exponential(\lambda)$ and $X\sim Exponential(\mu)$ letting $Z=X-Y$ a CDF of $Z$
$$P(X<Y)=P(X-Y<0)=P(Z<0)=F_{Z}(0)=1-\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}e^{-\mu (0)}=1-\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}=\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}$$

in your example $\lambda=2$ and $\mu=1$ so we have $P(Y>X)=\dfrac{1}{3}$

If a theoretical method seems out of your grasp, You can always simulate large sample and get rough estimate of probability (guaranteed to be close by Law of Large Numbers) here is some R code that could estimate it

> X=rexp(10000,1)
>
> Y=rexp(10000,2)
>
> Z=Y-X
>
> positiveZ=Z[Z>0]
>
> prob=length(positiveZ)/length(Z)
>
> prob

PS Thanks to Robert Isarel and Andre Nicolas for their solution to the CDF

Comment: How do you get the $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$? Thank you!!

Comment: going off link looking at Andres argument, we look at joint distribution of X an Y (and since independent will just be product of distribution) then integrate at region below line $y-x=0$

Comment: BTW, what is "X=rexp(10000,1)"? why is the 10000?

Comment: oh that rexp(n,1) just means simulate "n" amount of samples form distribution Exp(1), to get a good estimate you have to use a large sample size so I arbitrarily chose 10,000