# Prove that $\mathbb P(X>Y) =\frac{b}{a + b}$ if $X, Y$ are exponentially distributed with parameters $a$ and $b$.

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, independence, exponential-distribution

> Let $X, Y$ be an exponentially distributed random variables with parameters $a, b$. Then $X$ has pdf: 
>   $$f_X(x) =\begin{cases} a e^{-a x},& x\geq 0\\
> 0,& \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$ Suppose $X$ and $Y$ independent. Show that $$\mathbb P(X>Y) = \frac{b}{a+b}.$$

Now I thought the following:
$$f(x,y) = f_X(x)\ f_Y(y) = abe^{-ax -by},\qquad\text{for } x,y > 0.$$
And then $$\mathbb P(X>Y) = \int_0^\infty \int_0^x a b e^{-ax -by}\,dydx$$
However, if I solve this (manually or using Wolframalpha), I can't seem to end up with $\frac{b}{a+b}$. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at the pdf of $X-Y$ that I establish in my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1805587)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\begin{align*}
P(X>Y) &= \int_{0}^\infty\int_{0}^x abe^{-ax}e^{-by}\,dydx\\
&=\int_0^\infty ae^{-ax}\left[\int_0^xbe^{-by}\,dy\right]\,dx\tag 1\\
&=\int_0^\infty ae^{-ax}\left(1-e^{-bx}\right)\,dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty ae^{-ax}-a e^{-(a+b)x}\,dx\tag 2\\
&=1-\frac{a}{a+b}\int_0^\infty(a+b)e^{-(a+b)x}\,dx\tag 3\\
&=\frac{a+b-a}{a+b}\\&=\frac{b}{a+b}.
\end{align*}
where in

1. I recognize the inside integral as the cdf of $Y$
2. The left integral is the integral of a density so it is $1$ and
3. I make the integrand a density by multiplying and diving by the factor $a+b$ to make it equal $1$.

Answer (score 3):

There is an alternative approach [see this reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115022) by first determining the pdf of $X-Y$ (or find it in tables)

$$f(x) = \frac{ab}{a+b}
\begin{cases}e^{b x} & \text{if} \  x \leq 0\\
       e^{-a x} & \text{if} \  x \geq 0  \end{cases} \ \ \ (*)$$

Remarks:

1) the curve of $f$ is tent-shaped (see figure below for the case $a=3$ and $b=1$).

2) a particular, rather well-known case of (*), is for $a=b$, the so-called double exponential $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}$.

Then the result is

$$\int_{x=0}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{ab}{a+b}e^{-ax}dx=\frac{ab}{a+b}\frac{1}{a}=\frac{b}{a+b}.$$

[image]