# integrating exponential probability density functions

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions

assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent exponentially distributed RVs ($X, Y$ both $\geq 0$). in deriving $Pr(X > Y)$ i got stuck on the integral.

if $X > Y$ that means $X$ can take on any value $x \in [0, \infty]$ and $y \in [0, x]$, so we integrate the joint pdf with respect to $x$ from 0 to $\infty$ and with respect to $y$ from $0$ to $x$ - right?

$\begin{array}
Pr(X > Y) &= \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}P(X = x, Y = y)dxdy\\
&= \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}\lambda\mu e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\mu y}dxdy\\
\end{array}$

we rearrange to make it clear which integral goes with $x$ and which with $y$:

$\begin{array}
Pr(X > Y) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}\mu e^{-\mu y}dy\\ 
\end{array}$

the integral with respect to $x$ is from $[0, \infty]$ of the exponential pdf which is $1$ by definition but that would leave only $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}\mu e^{-\mu y}dy$ which looks wrong. what is wrong w/reasoning here?

another try:

$\begin{array}
Pr(X > Y) &= \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}\lambda\mu e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\mu y}dxdy\\
&= \lambda\mu\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\mu y}dxdy
\end{array}$

the inner part could be simplified to $e^{-\lambda x - \mu y}$ but that doesnt look simpler to integrate. can try to separate $dx$ and $dy$ again:

$\begin{array}
Pr(X > Y) &= \lambda\mu\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda x}dx\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} e^{-\mu y}dy\\
&= \lambda\mu\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda x}dx\left[\displaystyle\frac{-e^{-\mu y}}{\mu}\right]\big|^{x}_{0}\\
&= \lambda\mu\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda x}dx\left( \frac{-e^{-\mu x}}{\mu} - \frac{-e^{-\mu 0}}{\mu}\right)\\
&= \lambda\mu\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda x}dx\left( \frac{-e^{-\mu x}}{\mu} + 1\right)
\end{array}$

this is where im stuck. expected the CDF to of an exp to appear somewhere to make integration simpler. what went wrong in the reasoning/steps?

*update:* i would like to understand what is wrong with my reasoning which that post that is suggested as duplicate does not do. second, that post doesn't give a formal detailed derivation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $\mathbb P(X>Y) =\frac{b}{a + b}$ if $X, Y$ are exponentially distributed with parameters $a$ and $b$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805587/prove-that-mathbb-pxy-fracba-b-if-x-y-are-exponentially-distrib)

Comment: @Max no, that does not address my question even though it's the same problem

Comment: @jll The [top answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1805606) gives a formal derivation though. Regardless, the problem with your approach lies in the step, $r(X > Y) = \lambda\mu\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x}dx\int\limits_0^xe^{-\mu y}dy$. You can't treat these integrals separately because the integral with respect to $y$ depends on $x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try slightly easier approach with conditional probability (actually, the law of total probability). Let $X \sim \mathcal{E}xp(\lambda)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{E}xp(\mu)$, thus
\begin{align}
P(X>Y) &= \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X>y|Y=y)f_Y(y)dy\\
       &=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda y}\mu e^{-\mu y}dy\\
       &= \mu\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y (\lambda + \mu)}dy\\
       &=\frac{\mu}{\lambda + \mu}.
\end{align}
This is also called an exponential race, i.e., we computed the probability that $Y$ came before $X$, which equals the proportion of its pace w.r.t. other exponential variables' paces of decay.

Comment: how do you get the first term in the product $P(X > y | Y = y)$? i would assume this is $1 - P(X \leq y | Y = y)$, which is $1 - (1 - e^{-\lambda y}) = e^{-\lambda y}$ is that right? also how did you actually do the integral $e^{\lambda y}\mu e^{\mu y}dy$?

Comment: I've added one more step for the integration. Regarding the first term, it is just the law of total probability,$ P(A) = \int P(A|X)dF_X(x)$

Comment: still unclear about last step. isn't $\int e^{-y(\lambda + \mu)} = -\frac{e^{-y(\lambda+\mu)}}{\lambda + \mu}$? not sure how you got 1 in numerator

Comment: $ \lim_{y \to \infty } e^{-y} - e^{-0} = 0  -1 = -1. $

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies in the step,

$\begin{array}
Pr(X > Y) &= \lambda\mu\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda x}dx\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} e^{-\mu y}dy \end{array}$

You must integrate with respect to $y$ inside the integral of $x$:

$\begin{array}
Pr(X > Y) &= \lambda\mu\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda x}\left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} e^{-\mu y}dy\right)dx\\
 &= \lambda\mu\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda x}\left( \frac{-e^{-\mu x}}{\mu} + \frac{1}{\mu}\right)dx
\end{array}$