# Write a conditional probability expression with CDF/PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

When I read maths chapter, I found following conditional probability expression in a part of intermediate step and then directly gave the answer
\begin{equation}
I=\Pr\{x\leq y|x=t\}
\end{equation}
Here $x$ and $y$ are i.i.d exponential distributions.

Can someone please write $I$ by using CDF/PDF of $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substituting $x=t$ then 
$$
\begin{align}
I & =P(t \le y )\\
&=1-P(y \le t)
\end{align}
$$

($P(y \le t)$ is the CDF of $y$.)

Given $x$ is a random variable you may be interested in $P(y \le x)$
or equivalently $P(y - x \le 0)$. This concerns the difference of 2 i.i.d. exponential variates. The PDF of the difference of 2 exponential i.i.d. random variables has already been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115022/pdf-of-the-difference-of-two-exponentially-distributed-random-variables)

Comment: It should work, thanks @PM