# Determine the pdf of $U = \dfrac{X}{(X+Y)}$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, laplace-transform, exponential-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables and $X,Y \sim Exp(1)$.

> Determine the pdf of $U = \dfrac{X}{(X+Y)}$

I've only just started doing transforms and I'm not sure how to do $U = \dfrac{X}{(X+Y)}$.

Answer (score 1):

At the first step, we are going to compute the *CDF*. Next, we compute the *PDF* from the *CDF*.

\begin{align}
F_{U}(u) &= P(U\leq u) 
\\&= P(\frac{X}{X+Y}\leq u) 
\\&= P\big(X(1-u)\leq uY\big) 
\\&= P(X\leq \frac{u}{1-u}Y) 
\\&= \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\frac{u}{1-u}y}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy \quad (1)
\\&= \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\frac{u}{1-u}y}f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)dxdy \quad (2)
\end{align}

We can reach from Relation $(1)$ to Relation $(2)$ because $X$ and $Y$ are two **independent** random variables.

You must put the *PDF* of $X$ and $Y$ into Relation $(2)$ and after integration, you have the *CDF* of $U$. Finally, *PDF* = $\frac{d}{du}CDF$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$\mathbb{P}(U\leq u) = \mathbb{P}\left(X\leq \frac{u}{1-u}Y\right) = \mathbb{P}(X\leq Z)$$
if $Z\sim\text{Exp}((1-u)/u)$ independent to $X$. Moreover:
$$\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq Z_1) = \frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}$$
for $X_1\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ and $Z_1\sim\text{Exp}(\mu)$ independent. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115022/pdf-of-the-difference-of-two-exponentially-distributed-random-variables) why. Note that the notation of $U$ is quite suggestive.