# Lifespan of a machine with two breaking parts.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let us consider a machine with two parts X and Y. The time before part X goes out of service has an Exponential distribution with $\lambda = 1$ and the time before part Y goes out of service has an Exponential distribution with $\lambda = 0.05$ (its life expectation is 20 time units). When the part X breaks it is replaced in 1 time unit and the whole machine is not working during this time (hence the part Y is not ageing while the part X is being replaced). When part Y goes out of service, the whole machine is considered dead. What is the expectation of the random variable T, which stands for the time before death of the whole machine?

I have tried to consider conditioning on the lifespan of the part Y (I denoted this random variable T_Y) and on the number of times the part X breaks before the part Y goes out of service (N). 
$$ E(T) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}E(T|T_Y, N)P(N=k|T_Y)P(T_Y=t_{y})dt_{y} $$
But I am unsure of the formula. Also I would say that $E(T|T_{Y}, N) = t_{y} + k$ but I don't see why exactly. And what would be $ P(N=k|T_{y})$?

Comment: Just checking that I understand the question.  $E(T)$ is the expected time to failure of part $Y$ plus the expected number of times that part $X$ fails before part $Y$ fails.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the exponential distribution is memoryless, each time part $X$ is replaced, we have a new Bernoulli trial, where success means that part $Y$ fails before part $X.$  From the distribution of the difference of two independent exponentially-distributed random variables, (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115022/pdf-of-the-difference-of-two-exponentially-distributed-random-variables)) we calculate that the probability of success is $$p={.05\over1.05}$$ and we know that the expected number of trials until success is $${1\over p}=21$$

That means, that on average, part $X$ fails $20$ times before part $Y$ fails, so $$E(T)=20+E(Y)=20+20=40$$

just as we would have guessed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can I ask if I understand correctly? The number of fails of the part $X$ is independent from the time before the part $Y$ fails and has a geometric distribution (a sum of those Bernoulli trials you mentioned) with a probability of success $p = 1/21$?

Comment: So if we were to count the variance of the time before death it could be something like $Var(T) = 1-p/(p^2) + 1/(\lambda^2) = 20*21 +20^2$?

Comment: "The number of fails of the part $X$ is independent from the time before the part $Y$ fails."  I don't think that this is what you mean; I can't make sense of it.  I think that if $N$ is the number of failures of part $X$ before the failure of part $Y,$ then $N$ has the geometric distribution you describe.

Comment: I'm not sure about the variance.  If $Z$ is the lifetime of part $Y$ then $T=Z+N$  But surely $Z$ and $N$ are correlated, so you can't add up the variances.  This is really a different question, so you really should ask a different question if you want to pursue it.  I don't think I know how to do it, at least not without a lot of work.

Comment: You are right, I can not compute the variance as a sum of variances.