# What is the probability that the time until the first machine break-down is at least 5 days?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

A factory contains 8 machines. Any one of the machines can breakdown independently of the other machines following an exponential distribution with a mean value of 10 days. What is the probability that the time until the first machine break-down is at least 5 days?

obviously $\mu = 10$ and hence, $\lambda = 1/10$

I think we have that $P(X>5) = 1-P(X<5) = 1-(1-e^-5\times0.1)) = 0.60653$
but this is just for one machine. I'm not sure how to deal with the fact that there are 8 machines.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be independent exponentially distributed random variables with rate parameters $\lambda_1,\dots, \lambda_n$.  Then

$$\min \left \{X_1,\dotsc,X_n \right \}$$

is also exponentially distributed, with parameter

$$\lambda = \lambda_1+\dotsb+\lambda_n.$$
(Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Distribution_of_the_minimum_of_exponential_random_variables).)

So you need to calculate $\mathbb P(X\geq 5)$ where $X$ has an exponential distribution with parameter $\frac8{10}$.

Comment: So would i be correct in saying i should have $1-(1-e^(-5\times1.2))$

Comment: @ho_howdy That is correct. Make sure to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) in case you are satisfied with it

Comment: that returns 0.00247, that's surely not the correct answer?

Comment: @ho_howdy Sorry, I made a small error: The parameter is $\frac8{10}$ and not $\frac{10}8$... So the correct answer is $e^{-4}$.

Comment: understood. thank you for your help!

Comment: @ho_howdy You're welcome!

Comment: Hi, i have another question regarding this. What is the distribution of the time until the first machine breaks down?

I think that the distribution of time between two break downs is also exponentially distributed. But since there are 8 machines, I am thinking it is Gamma distributed? But i am not sure.

Comment: @how_howdy The distribution of the time until the first breakdown is exponential and so is the distribution of the time of any given machine. For the distribution of time *between* two breakdowns see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115022/pdf-of-the-difference-of-two-exponentially-distributed-random-variables