# What is the probability distribution of a random variable with distribution function $F_{Y-X}(z)=1-\frac{\nu}{\nu+\lambda} e^{-\lambda z}$?

Tags: probability, random

I have this:

$F_{Y-X}(z)=1-\frac{\nu}{\nu+\lambda} e^{-\lambda z}$.

I have to find a probability distribution to work with and then obtain $E(Y-X)$ and some other data based on the distribution function given above.
I've tried by just founding the first derivative but it turned out not to be a true density function.

I can notice the distribution function is quite similar to that of an exponential distribution, but I can't figure out any way I can get a density function out of it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ known to be exponential RVs with parameters $\nu$ and $\lambda$ (or vice-versa)? If so you can find the density of $Z=Y-X$ through the transformation technique. Alternatively, you may differentiate $F_Z(z)$ given here and find the region $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_A f_Z(z) dz =1$, which may be a little trickier than the former idea.

Comment: Actually, having the distributions of $Y$ and $X$ individually would make computing $\mathbb{E}(Y-Z)=\mathbb{E}(Y)-\mathbb{E}(X)$ trivial. Where does this problem come from anyway, and is this the full set up or is there any information you did not include here?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I've just realized I was doing it the dumb way, but the problem was proposed liked that. I have the source in spanish, give a while and I will translate, I'm finding it very tough.

Comment: Here is the whole problem set [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JEPWFZjUjKsOv518i2az2xNVTfjxMg1a/view?usp=sharing) We were given the result of (1.1.1) and were supposed to work using it.

Comment: I am not so good with English, so please let me know if there's something you don't understand.

Comment: You can find the distribution of $Y-X$ here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115022/pdf-of-the-difference-of-two-exponentially-distributed-random-variables

Comment: Thank you @Math1000, it was very helpful!