# How to Find CDF of $T_1-T_2$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

Given that $T_1, T_2$ are iid $\text{exp}(\lambda)$ variates.

I want to find the cdf $F_T(t)$ where $T=T_1-T_2$

**My Attempt**

$F_T(t) =_1 P(T<t) = P(T_1-T_2<t) = P(T_1<T_2 + t)$

Where $=_1$ is true according to the definition of CDF.

But I'm stuck here, how can I continue from this step?

Comment: Are $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ independent?

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron yes they are.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115022/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ are independent then

If $t\geq 0$,

$$P(T\leq t)=P(T_{1}-T_{2}\leq t)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{T_{1}-T_{2}\leq t\}})\\=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{T_{1}\leq t-t_{2}\}}|T_{2}=t_{2}))=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{t+t_{2}}\lambda^{2}e^{-\lambda (t_{1}+t_{2})}dt_{1}\,dt_{2}=1-\frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{2}$$.

This evaluates to

If $t<0$. Then

$$P(T\leq t)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{T_{1}\leq t-t_{2}\}}|T_{2}=t_{2}))=\\\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbf{1}_{\{t_{2}+t\geq 0,t_{1}\leq t_{2}+t\}}\lambda^{2}e^{-\lambda (t_{1}+t_{2})}dt_{1}\,dt_{2}=\\\int_{-t}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{t+t_{2}}\lambda^{2}e^{-\lambda (t_{1}+t_{2})}dt_{1}\,dt_{2}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot e^{\lambda t}$$.

So :-

$$\large F_{T}(t)=\begin{cases} 1-\frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{2}\quad, t\geq 0\\\frac{e^{\lambda t}}{2}\quad,t<0\end{cases}$$

The pdf can be found correspondingly by differentiating wrt $t$.

$$\large f_{T}(t)=\begin{cases} \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda t}}{2}\quad, t\geq 0\\\frac{\lambda e^{\lambda t}}{2}\quad,t<0\end{cases}$$

Comment: All of them are exponential integrals. I don't think you will have trouble in evaluating them.

Comment: @dan I have edited my answer.

Comment: What are those E's? Expected value maybe? Can't the above be re-written without using E in the formula (I didn't learn what are those ones to...)

Comment: I think you have something wrong with integral limits, I don't understand why u split to cases when t<0 and when t>=0...

Comment: $\mathbb{E}$ stands for expected value. And you can write the integrals in terms of the joint pdf. The limits will be the same(in fact what I did is the justification of why that is the case). If you are having trouble understanding why I split those integrals then you should brush up the definitions as I don't think your concepts are clear.

Comment: The case for $t\leq 0$ has to be separate because in that situation when you are integrating wrt to $t_{1}$ , the pdf of $T_{1}$ is zero in the region then $t_{1}\leq 0$. So you have to integrate in the region when $0\leq t_{1}\leq t+t_{2}$ and for this to happen , $t_{2}$ must be such that $t+t_{2}\geq 0$ .

Comment: This predicament is no longer there when we assume $t\geq 0$. Because in that case $t+t_{2}$ is always non-negative and you can integrate as I did in the first case

Comment: Also @Dan if you use the pdf of $T_{1}-T_{2}$ as given 
in the comments https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115022/pdf-of-the-difference-of-two-exponentially-distributed-random-variables  . You will end up with the same result as I did . If $x>0$ you integrate from $0$ to $x$ . And if $x<0$ you integrate from $-\infty to x$. Also you can use my cdf and differentiate to get the pdf as given here.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming independence  between $T_1$ and $T_2$ you have to evaluate the following integral

$$F_T(t)=\int \int_{T<t}f_{T_1}(t_1)f_{T_2}(t_2)d t_1 d t_2$$

thus do a drawing of the integration region and solve the double integral.

Observe that integral bounds change according with $T>0$ or $T<0$