# The expected value of $Y=e^X$ where $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value

Since there is no definite answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176196/calculate-the-expected-value-of-y-ex-where-x-sim-n-mu-sigma2) here but many good tips, I tried to compute $E(e^x)$ myselfe and this is what I got:
$$
E(e^X)=\displaystyle{\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^x e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{x-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx = 
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\frac{2x\sigma^2-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\frac{2x\sigma^2-(x^2-2x\mu+\mu^2)}{2\sigma^2}}dx =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\frac{-(x^2-2x(\sigma^2+\mu)+\mu^2)}{2\sigma^2}}dx
$$

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\frac{-(x-(\sigma^2+\mu))^2+2\sigma^2\mu+\sigma^4}{2\sigma^2}}dx =e^{{\frac{2\sigma^2\mu+\sigma^4}{2\sigma^2}}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{\frac{-(x-(\sigma^2+\mu))^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx = e^{\mu}e^{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}
$$

Is this ok? But does this also prove that $E(|e^X|)$ is finite? If not, how can I show that?

Comment: You could have easily checked, say, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution to see that the MGF is $e^{\mu t + \sigma^2 t^2/2}$ which at $t=1$ gives this result. Your procedure of completing the square is also correct. As for $E[|e^X|]$ you have that $e^X=|e^X|$ for real $X$...

Comment: Thank you Ian, somehow I missed that $|e^X|=e^X$ for real $X$. How can I show this or is there any proof maybe here allready?

Comment: @KingDingeling $e^x>0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is common knowledge. Depending on your definition, this might come directly from it, and if not, I'm sure there's proof somewhere around here. But it's odd for you to study probability, yet ask such elementary questions.

Comment: Yes but $e^{-2}\neq e^2$. Somehow I think that this is really stupid but wow am I stuck... Ah, my mistake is that I think that $|e^x|=e^{|x|}$. It's not.

Comment: @Jakobian has been a looooong day but you are right.