# distribution of X*Y with X and Y both i.i.d. with a U(0,1) distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ both being i.i.d. with a $U(0,1)$ distribution. I am trying to calculate the cumulative distribution function of $Z=X*Y$. Which would be the most efficient way to do this? Until now, I tried t put something together from here and try a similar approach: [Finding distribution function of $Y/X$ and probability density function of $X+Y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184433/finding-distribution-function-of-y-x-and-probability-density-function-of-xy)

However, I am really unsure if I can work similarly in my case.
So this is my approach:

$$
F_{Z}(z) = P(X*Y \leq z) = \int_0^1 P \left( Y \leq \frac{z}{x} \right)*\frac{1}{f_X(x)}dx
$$

Is this approach still correct? Furthermore I am quite unsure how to continue from here, so any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I would integrate the joint distribution over the region $0\le x\le 1$, $0\le y\le 1$, $xy\le z$. It is a simple double integral.

Comment: since $f_X(x)=1$ this will give the correct answer, but for other distributions, I believe you need to multiply by $f_X(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The law of total probability states that
$$P(XY \leq z) = \int_0^1 P(XY \leq z \: | \: X=x) f_X(x) \: dx,$$
where $f_X(x)=1$ for $x \in [0,1]$, since $X \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$, and by independence we get that
$$P(XY \leq z \: | \: X=x) = P(xY \leq z \: | \: X=x) = P(Y \leq \frac{z}{x}).$$
Now by definition of the uniform CDF we get, that
$$P(Y \leq \frac{z}{x}) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if $\frac{z}{x} \geq 1$} \\ 
                                        \frac{z}{x} & \text{ if $\frac{z}{x} \in (0,1)$} \\
                                        0           & \text{ if $\frac{z}{x} \leq 0$ }
   \end{cases}.$$
And since we only need to consider $z,x \in (0,1)$ we get, that $P(Y \leq \frac{z}{x})=1$ for $x \leq z$ and $P(Y \leq \frac{z}{x}) = \frac{z}{x}$ for $x> z$. Plugging this into the integral we get that
\begin{align*} P(XY \leq z) &= \int_0^z \: dx + \int_z^1 \frac{z}{x} \: dx \\
&= z - z \ln(z) \\
&= z \ln(\frac{e}{z})
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much - helps a lot!