# Possible to evaluate definite integral of inverse trigonometric function as function of $Y$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Suppose 
$Y = \sqrt{2T}\cos(U)$,  $ 0 \le u \le \pi $, and  $ 0 \le \cos^{-1}(\frac{y}{\sqrt {2t}}) \le \pi  ) $, so $ -1 \le \frac{y}{\sqrt{2t}} \le 1 $, with all $ \mathbb{R}$. Now I have the iterated integral
$$ G(y)= \int_{0}^{y}\int_{0}^{\cos^{-1}(\frac{y}{\sqrt {2t}})}   \frac{e^{-t}}{\pi }  \mathrm{d}u \mathrm{d}t$$

Evaluating the inner integral, I have

$$
G(y)=P(Y\le y)=\int_{0}^{y}   \frac{e^{-t} \cos^{-1}(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2t}})}{\pi } \mathrm{d}t
$$

where $G(y)$ is a CDF of $Y$.

Here I'm stuck. Maybe my integration conditions are erroneous? Any help on how to find this (or the correct) integral as a function of $Y$, would be appreciated.

(This  question follows from my previous one: [Help solving CDF for transformation of $ \ge 2 $ random variables or if it's impossible.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190809/help-solving-cdf-for-transformation-of-ge-2-random-variables-or-if-its-imp)).

Comment: Once again, you are neglecting the signs since Y might be negative hence the interval (0,y) in the integral should be (-oo,y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisely the kind of example where the functional approach explained [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30966/6179) works better... Here is how to apply it in the present case.

One may find difficult to juggle with all the inequalities that the computation of the CDF of $Y$ involves. Instead, one can start with any suitable function $\varphi$ and note that, by definition of the distribution of $(T,U)$,
$$
\mathrm E(\varphi(Y))=\mathrm E(\varphi(\sqrt{2T}\cos(U)))=\int_0^\pi\int_0^\infty \varphi(\sqrt{2t}\cos(u))\frac1\pi\mathrm e^{-t}\mathrm dt\mathrm du.
$$
The change of variables $(t,u)\to(y,x)$ with $y=\sqrt{2t}\cos(u)$ and $x=\sqrt{2t}\sin(u)$ yields $2t=x^2+y^2$ and $\mathrm dt\mathrm du=\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$ with $y$ in $(-\infty,+\infty)$ and $x\geqslant0$. Hence,
$$
\mathrm E(\varphi(Y))=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\varphi(y)\frac1\pi\mathrm e^{-y^2/2}\left(\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}\mathrm dx\right)\mathrm dy.
$$
The inner integral is independent of $y$ and is equal to $\frac12\sqrt{2\pi}$ hence
$$
\mathrm E(\varphi(Y))=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\varphi(y)\gamma(y)\mathrm dy,\qquad\text{with}\quad  \gamma(y)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm e^{-y^2/2}.
$$
This identity holds for every (bounded measurable) function $\varphi$. This proves that the distribution of $Y$ has standard normal density $\gamma$.

**Nota:** The very same approach starting from $(Y,X)=(\sqrt{2T}\cos(U),\sqrt{2T}\sin(U))$ shows that $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. standard normal, a fact which is at the basis of [Box-Muller method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) of simulation of normal random variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you want  the region $0 < u < \pi$, $-1 \le y/\sqrt{2t} \le 1$, you'll need $t \ge y^2/2$, but I don't see why you want $u \le \cos^{-1}(y/\sqrt{2t})$ or $t \le y$ unless there's something you aren't telling us.
So if you want to integrate $e^{-t}/\pi$ over this region it should just be

$$ \int_{y^2/2}^\infty \int_0^\pi \frac{e^{-t}}{\pi}\ du\ dt $$

Comment: to explain why $ t \le y $, I should have included that this integral is to find a CDF function for $Y$. It relates to my previous one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190809/help-solving-cdf-for-transformation-of-ge-2-random-variables-or-if-its-imp