# absolutely continuous distributions

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let ($\Omega$,F,P) a probability space. Let $A,B$ Borel limitate subsets of $R^n$ with positive lebesgue measure $X: \Omega\rightarrow A$ and $Y:\Omega\rightarrow B$ two independent random variables with distributions absolutely continous with respect to *Lebesgue measure* of $R^n$: $D=|X-Y|$

Please help proving that $D$ is absolutely continous rispect lebesgue measure and express it in terms of the distributions of $X$ and $Y$.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried / where you are getting stuck. You will find that people on this site will be significantly faster to help you if you do that; that way, we know exactly what help you need.

Comment: I have tried to solve it by usin the partition function

Comment: And what did it yield? Show your work! (Beware though that "partition function" does not mean what you think.)

Comment: $F(t)=P[D\leq t]=P[|X-Y|\leq t]=P[y\in B_{(x,t)}]=\int_{R^n}(\int_{R^n}1_{B(x,t)}(y)g(y)dy)f(x)dx$

Comment: Why the CDF should help to establish the absolute continuity?

Comment: the distribution is absolutely continous if it has a density which is the derivate of the partition function.I must prove that F(t) is $C^1$

Comment: Not $C^1$, since a priori the density is only integrable. But since your computation of the CDF seems stalled, you might try another characterization of AC... (Unrelated, what you call "partition function" is in fact the "cumulative distribution function".)

Comment: but this characterization of AC is the unic that permits us to calculate then the density

Comment: can anyone give me another characterization of AC

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_measures

Comment: but to express the  distribution of D in terms of X and Y we must find its density

Comment: No. See answer.

Comment: Ok, but how can I now express the distribution of D in terms of the distributions of X and Y

Comment: You might want to use [the general approach](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/30966/).

Comment: Can you give me a hint ?

Comment: I just did... Did you read the answer I linked to? If you did, it should suggest an approach to your question.

Comment: I red the answer but I don't understand how to modificate it in this case because $x,y\in R^n$ and we want $w=|x-y|\in R\quad$ z=?

Answer (score 2):

This is to debunk the claim, repeated several times by the OP, that, to show that some distribution is absolutely continuous, one must first compute its density.

Consider the case $n=1$. For $y$ in $\mathbb R$ and $C\subseteq\mathbb R$, let $C(y)=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid|x-y|\in C\}$, thus, $C(y)=(y+C)\cup(y-C)$. The Lebesgue measure is invariant by the translations and the reflections hence, for every measurable $C$, $\mathrm{Leb}(y+C)=\mathrm{Leb}(y-C)=\mathrm{Leb}(C)$ and $\mathrm{Leb}(C(y))\leqslant2\,\mathrm{Leb}(C)$. In particular, if $C$ is negligible, so is $C(y)$, for each $y$.

Now, let $C$ such that $\mathrm{Leb}(C)=0$. Then $P[D\in C]=P[X\in C(Y)]$ and, by independence,
$$
P[X\in C(Y)]=\int_{\mathbb R} P[X\in C(y)]\,\mathrm dP_Y(y).
$$
If the distribution of $X$ is absolutely continuous, $P[X\in C(y)]=0$ for every $y$ since $\mathrm{Leb}(C(y))=0$ for every $y$. Thus, $P[D\in C]=0$. This holds for every negligible set $C$ hence the distribution of $D$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: but to prove that Leb(C(y))=0 in tis case we can't use $C(y)=(y+C)\cup (y-C)$ because $y\in R^n$ and $C\subset R$

Comment: Thus you need another way to prove that Leb(C(y))=0. Hint: spherical coordinates.

Comment: Is this true:  $|X-Y|\in C\implies C(y)=(C\times S^{n-1}-y)\cup (y+C\times S^{n-1})$

Comment: but I don't finf the way how to use spherical coordinates to calculate the density