# Distribution of higher powers than 2 of a gaussian distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, normal-distribution

If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, then $X^2 \sim \chi^2(1)$. What about higher powers of $X$? I know that the Gamma Distribution is a generalization of the $\chi^2$ distribution, but I don't know how the Gamma Distribution parameters relate to the square part of $\chi^2$.

In particular I'm trying to calculate $X^4$, where $X \sim \mathcal{N} \left(0,\frac{1}{N} \right)$. How do you even take on such a problem?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Yet again an incorrect edit approved by you... Please revise your behaviour in this domain.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For every positive $a$, the distribution of $T=|X|^a$ has density
$$
\frac2{a\sqrt{2\pi}}t^{(1/a)-1}\exp\left(-\tfrac12t^{2/a}\right)\,\mathbf 1_{t>0}.
$$
This follows from the usual change of variables method explained [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30966/6179).

For example, the distribution of $Z=X^4$ has density
$$
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}z^{3/4}}\exp\left(-\tfrac12\sqrt{z}\right)\,\mathbf 1_{z>0}.
$$

Comment: According to the general formula, for a=4 the exponent for z should be 1/3, not -3/4 (unless i'm missing something)?

Comment: Read (1/a)-1, not 1/(a-1) (which would be absurd, say for a=1).

Comment: Sorry for the edit, I don't know why I interpreted this exponent in such a silly way. It obviously is all correct right know.

Comment: @Did this distribution seems not normalizable? I put it into mathematica and the integral over all $z$ is divergent. How do you explain that?

Comment: @user1936752 The density in my answer has integral 1, as every distribution has.

Comment: Ah sorry, I realize now I need to take the absolute z if it is negative

Comment: @user1936752 No, the density is only defined by the function in my answer for $z>0$. For $z<0$, the density is zero, obviously.

Comment: This is cool, thanks. Is there also something for X^3 (without absolute value)?

Comment: @divB Indeed there is., as shows the general methodology explained [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/30966/).

Comment: @Did Does the distribution of $X^a$ has some name as it has for $a=2$? Maybe, it is part of some family?

Comment: @Marcel One could try *Generalized Gamma Distribution*, see Stacy EW. A Generalization of the Gamma Distribution. The Annals of Mathematical Statistics. 1962;33(3):pp. 1187-1192. Available at: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2237889.

Comment: @Did Do you have any references related to the sum of such variables? In particular bounds on their tails?

Comment: @ThomasAhle If you add to it some personal input, this could make for a good new question on this site...