# Can we find the expected value of $Z$, where $Z=X^p$, and $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_X,\sigma_X)$?

Tags: integration, random-variables, expected-value

Can we find the expected value of $Z$, where $Z=X^p$ with $p>0$ and $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_X,\sigma_X)$ ?

With the help of [Gaussian distribution raised to a power](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1228316), I think the pdf of Z should be, 
$$f_Z(z)=pz^{p-1}f_X(x).$$
So, expected value should be,
$$\mathrm{E}(Z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{pz^pf_X(x)\mathrm{d}z}.$$

I am stuck with,
$$\mathrm{E}(Z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{(\mu_X+\sigma_{X} y)^{1/p} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left( -\frac{y^2}{2} \right)\mathrm{d}y},$$
where $y=\frac{x-\mu_X}{\sigma_X}$

Can we solve this?

Comment: Taking a look at [moments of normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments) might help.

Comment: You probably mean $|X|^p$. The pdf needs to be modified in that case.