# What distribution has $X^n$ if $X$ is normal distributed?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

Let $X$ be a random variable with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma ^2$, i.e. $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma ^2)$.What is the distribution of $Y= X^n$, $n \in \mathbb {N}.$ ?

I know what distributribution has $Y=aX+b$, but I have not found anything for this case.

**Revised version:** In the end, only the expectation of $Y$ is needed, not its distribution.

Comment: can you calculate the distributional function of $X^n$ ?

Comment: I don´t understand what you are trying to say, @Chival

Comment: How do you compute the distribution of G(X), say when G is monotonous and one knows the distribution of X?

Comment: If $Y=g(x)$, then  $$f_Y (y)=f_X (g^{-1}(y)) \left| \frac{\partial (g^{-1}(y))}{\partial y} \right| $$ . But I don´t obtain any satisfactory result in this case..

Comment: Yet this yields a full answer for every odd exponent n. And now for the even exponents...

Comment: What do you mean, @Did ?

Comment: I mean that "this yields a full answer for every odd exponent n. And now for the even exponents..."

Comment: But, what do you need to distinguish when $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is odd or even?

Comment: @Edin_91 Even functions are not monotonic in X

Comment: Thanks, Bey:) I  have found the next http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html but does not help me a lot...

Comment: If $n$ is odd then $X^n \leq y$ is equivalent to $X \leq y^{1/n}$. If $n$ is even, then $X^n \leq y$ for $y \geq 0$ is equivalent to $X \in [-y^{1/n},y^{1/n}]$, and is impossible for $y < 0$. Work from there to get a CDF, and then differentiate to get a PDF.

Comment: When you google "powers gaussian", the first thing that comes up is [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683359/distribution-of-higher-powers-than-2-of-a-gaussian-distribution) MSE post by Did.

Comment: I don´t finish to understand why I have to sepate the case that n is odd or even.

Comment: @Edin_91 Because of differences in monotonicity. When $n$ is odd, $f(x)=x^n$ is an increasing function. When $n$ is even, it is not. This means that you have to handle events of the form $X^n \leq y$ differently in the two cases. Think about the graphs of $x^2$ and $x^3$; for $x^2$, the $y$ values are below $64$ on $(-8,8)$ (a bounded interval). For $x^3$, the $y$ values are below $64$ on $(-\infty,4)$ (an unbounded interval).

Comment: Oh, okay, I have undestood! So, with the formula $$f_Y (y)=f_X (g^{-1}(y)) \left| \frac{\partial (g^{-1}(y))}{\partial y} \right|$$ I can obtain the case when n is only? And the other case?

Comment: I have realised that for solving my problem I don´t need the distribution of $X^n$, do I? It would be enought to compute $${\mathbb E} [ e^{Y}] = {\mathbb E} [e^{X^n}]=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{x^n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma ^2}} e^{{-1 \over {2\sigma^2}}(x-\mu)^2}dx$$ and building a perfect square.

Comment: uhm.. why not just use the moment generating function?

Answer (score 3):

**"In the end, only the expectation of Y is needed, not its distribution."** This a *typical famous* university exam question.

As Did already mentioned $E(X^n)=0$ for n being odd. Now for $n$ even ($2m$ say and WLOG assume $\sigma^2=1$),
$$E(X^{2m})=2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{2m}\exp(-x^{2}/2)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx$$
Substitute, $y=x^2/2$ to make the above as a $Gamma$ integral. The final answer is $\frac{2^m \times\Gamma(m+0.5)}{\sqrt\pi}$ which is $1\times3\times5...\times (2m-1)$