# CDF of Gaussian Distribution Raised to a Power

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral, cumulative-distribution-functions

Say X ~ $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ what would be the CDF of Y=X^a (where a is an integer). I have seen how to get the PDF which would theoretically give the CDF but I'm not sure how to get a closed form solution, say using erf() like the standard normal cdf form.

Reference: [Distribution of higher powers than 2 of a gaussian distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683359/distribution-of-higher-powers-than-2-of-a-gaussian-distribution)

Comment: First define how you raise to power $a\notin\mathbb{Z}$ before you talk about the pdf of $X^a$.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking only about integers; I'll add that in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a is a positive odd integer, then $Y=X^a$ has a symmetric distribution.  Thus, for the complementary CDF (CCDF) of $Y$, we obtain:
$$\overline F_Y(x) = P(X^a>x) = \overline \Phi(x^{1/a}),$$
for all $x>0$, where $\overline \Phi(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_z^\infty e^{-u^2/2}du$ is the CCDF of the standard Normal distribution. Or, for the CDF:
$$
F_Y(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
  \Phi(x^{1/a})&, x>0\\
   1-\Phi(|x|^{1/a})&, x\le 0
\end{array}\right.,
$$
Where $\Phi(x) = 1-\overline\Phi(x)$ is the standard Normal CDF.

This solves half of the problem.  For $a$ even, $Y$ is positive and for all $x>0$, we have
$$
\overline F_Y(x) = P(|X|> x^{1/a}) = 2\overline\Phi(x^{1/a}). 
$$
Which gives
$$
F_Y(x) = 2 \Phi(x^{1/a}) - 1,\ \ x\ge 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks so much!