# Finding pdf's from a equation?

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

Please can someone expalin how i do question 8i in this picture, I have tried finding X in terms of theta but don't know then how to turn this into a pdf (if that is even what it is looking for)? I have basically got to x=δtan(θ)but don't know how to contiune?? Please help?

Comment: To sum up, the question is to compute the PDF of x=δ.tan(θ) when θ is uniform on $(0,\pi/2)$ (or on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, this is not quite clear). [Which approaches](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30938/given-the-pdf-of-independent-rvs-i-and-r-how-to-find-cdf-of-w-i2r/30966#30966) do you know to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$\delta\tan\theta\leq x\iff\theta\leq\arctan\frac{x}{\delta}$$

That gives you a possibility to find the cdf. For pdf you take its derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Given $\delta$, If we assume that $\theta$ is uniformly distributed over $[\frac{-\pi}2 \frac{\pi}2]$, the point $x$ is distributed according to Cauchy distribution:
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi\delta \left[1 + \left(\frac{x}\delta\right)^2 \right]}.
$$