# Distribution of a fraction (probability theory)

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Let $\beta$ follow a random normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $c \cdot \sigma^2$. Let $\gamma$ be similarly distributed with mean $\nu$ and variance $k \cdot \sigma^2$. 
I need an approximate confidence interval of 
$$Z = - \frac{\beta} {2 \cdot \gamma}$$
By approximate, I figure we can assume independence, and use our estimates of the data involved, but I am not completely sure how to do it. Will it involve a T-distribution?

The estimates are $\mu = 300, \nu = -5, \sigma^2 = 40000$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Gaussian_ratio_distribution

Comment: Have a look at this very recent question and its answers http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1679650