# Product of a discrete and absolutely continuous random variable, part deux

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have the independent random variables $U\sim N(0,1)$, $V\sim N(0,1)$, $W\sim b(1,1/2)$

I define $X=WU + (1-W)(V+1)$. I need to determine that $X$ is absolutely continuous, and determine a density function of $X$. I have the same problem as with my earlier question: I really don't know how the joint distribution is defined for a discrete and an absolutely continuous variable.

Bonus question: I also need to determine if $UW$ is a discrete  variable. I'm thinking yes, since ${UW=0}\supseteq{W=0}$, and $P({W=0})=1/2$.

Comment: If anyone else could explain the given answer, that would be appreciated!

Comment: Did the link help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f_X(x)=\tfrac12f_U(x)+\tfrac12f_{V+1}(x)=\tfrac12f_U(x)+\tfrac12f_{V}(x-1)$$
Note that $UW$ is neither purely discrete nor purely continuous since its distribution has an atom of mass $\frac12$ at $0$ and the rest of the distribution is a densitable measure of mass $\frac12$.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea why this result is correct, or how you derived it. Furthermore, I haven't taken any measure theory courses yet, so I'm pretty sure a simpler answer is expected of me, of the bonus question at least.

Comment: You cite "absolutely continous", "density function", "joint distribution", but you are allowed no measure theory notions? What is this course?

Comment: This is the freshman "Introduction to Probability Theory" course at Aarhus University. Maybe things are structured or named differently in US universities?

Comment: How do they suggest to compute PDFs in general?

Comment: We have a table of probability density functions of common distributions. We mostly work with independent variables, so finding a joint density usually isn't that bad. This is why I am somewhat lost when it comes to the more specific properties of PDFs.

Comment: No general definition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16223/discussion-between-elswyyr-and-did).

Comment: Most general definitions I've got is that the function must be non-negative and integrate to 1 over the reals.
Oh, and that the probability of an event in a subset is the integral of the PDF over the subset. And that is about as general as it goes.

Comment: These are not a definition, at most properties. How do you determine/check that some function $h$ is the PDF of the random variable $X$?

Comment: Well, if I know the distribution function of the variable, I can find the derivative. Otherwise, well, I don't.

Comment: To sum up, you have no definition of the PDF of a random variable at hand? This might be problematic if one wants to solve exercises involving PDFs... :-)

Comment: Indeed. Unfortunately, this is an exam set from a previous year, so it is stuff I need to be able to answer.

Comment: Then you might find [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/30966/6179) useful.