# Determining the joint density of W and Z when W = X/(1-X) and Z = Y/(1-Y)

Tags: probability-theory

The exercise relates to joint density $$f(x,y)= Cx^{\alpha-1}y^{\beta-1}(1-x-y)^{\gamma -1}$$ for $x > 0, y > 0, x + y \leq 1$ and $$C = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)\Gamma(\gamma)}.
$$
I have already shown the marginal densities. Now I'm being asked to find the joint density of W and Z where $$W = \frac{X}{1-X},\qquad Z = \frac{Y}{1-Y}.
$$
My thought is to solve $$F(w,z) = \int^\frac{x}{1-x}_{-\infty}\int^\frac{y}{1-y}_{-\infty}f(x,y) dx dy.
$$
Am I on the right path? Thank you.

Comment: Why not use [the most powerful and simple method](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/30966/6179)?

Comment: Although I am sure that your method works, this complex function is far too complicated for me to perform with the technique. It has been more than 15 years since I have had to perform double integration. My calculus is extremely rusty. If you don't mind, how would I start the problem using your technique?

Comment: Stupid me thought this was explained in details in the post I linked to. What is a specific step where you have a problem to *follow the lights*?

Comment: Perhaps I'm making this more difficult than it actually is, but do I write both W and Z in terms of X and Y respectively and then sub for X and Y in the function? This substitution then raises the question on the limits of the integrals.

Comment: ?? You already have "both W and Z in terms of X and Y". Sorry but unless you are much more specific about what is stopping you, I cannot help.

Comment: Let me try to be clearer. Sub X with $\frac{W}{1+W}$ and sub Y with $\frac{z}{1+z}$? Then integrate $dz$ from 0 to 1 and then $dw$ from 0 to  1?

Comment: Sorry, you seem to be making a mishmash of the very precise method I presented in the other post. Let me suggest you explain step by step how you are applying it to the present case.

Comment: $E(g(v))=C\int \int g(v)[0\leq x\leq 1]\cdot \frac{x}{1-x}\cdot [0\leq y\leq 1]\frac{y}{1-y}dxdy$. Is this the correct way to set it up using your method?

Comment: Absolutely not, you are confusing random variables and their PDFs.

Comment: So X and Y both have marginal densities of a Beta function.Should I be looking at that function instead?

Comment: I have been trying for many hours to get this problem worked out. Everything that I try with Maple comes out incorrect. So I am obviously not setting up the problem incorrectly. Could you help me out with that? I am sure that I can perform the calculations once I see what I need to do. Thank you.

Comment: $$E(g(W,Z))=\iint g(x/(1-x),y/(1-y))f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy=\cdots=\iint g(w,z)f_{W,Z}(w,z)dwdz$$