# random variables independence

Tags: probability, random-variables

I need to check if Z and W are dependent or not.

```
X,Y ~ Exp(2)
```

Then I define: `Z=X-Y` , `W=X+Y`.

Now How I can check that Z and W are dependent or not ?

I know from the teory that I should show that `f(z,w) = f(z)f(w)` , but I dont see how I do it here.

Thanks for help.

Comment: The observation that $$P(Z\lt W)=1$$ should be nearly enough to conclude. That, or computing the density of $(Z,W)$ by [the standard method](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/30966/6179).

Comment: @Did , By showing that it's equals 1 , what it's gives me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Z$ and $W$ are indeed independent then e.g. $P(Z>1,W<1)=P(Z>1)P(W<1)>0$.

This contradicts that $P(Z<W)=1$ as mentioned in the comment of @Did.