# Find the distribution of $Z = 1/X_1 + 1/X_2$

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> Find the distribution of $Z = 1/X_1 + 1/X_2$, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ follow normal distribution.

I have $2$ variables with normal distribution, $X_1$ and $X_2$.
How can I find the distribution of:
 $$Z = \frac{1}{X_1} + \frac{1}{X_2}?$$

How can I, then, generalize the method for $n$ variables? 
$$\left(Z'= \frac{1}{X_1} + \frac{1}{X_2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{X_n}\right)$$

Thanks!

Comment: Are $X_1$ and $X_2$ independant ?

Comment: The question doesn't clarify, but let's assume they are, for simplicity reasons.

Comment: Did you try to apply the standard procedure? Where were you stuck?

Comment: @Did I am not a mathematician, I am a programmer; I need this for a simulation. I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to approach the problem..

Comment: Example in action: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/30966/

Comment: If you only need it for simulation, then it is easier to just use a random generator for X1 and X2 and then calculate Z.

Comment: Thank you.
I just would like to know the theoritical result in order to confirm the simulation results afterwards.