# Conditional pdf of product of two exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have two independent random variables say $X$, $Y$. Both of them follow exponential distribution with parameter $λ$ i.e $X\sim λe^{−λx}$ and $Y\sim λe^{−λy}$. I want to find the pdf of $Z=XY$ given $X>c$ i.e $p_{Z/X>c}(z/x>c)$ where $c$ is a positive fixed number.

Can I write it like this:
$$p_{Z/X>c}(z/x>c)=\frac{p_{Z}(z)}{P_{X}(X>c)},$$
or is the following formula right
$$\int_{c}^{\infty}p_{Y}(z/x)p_{X}(x)dx\ ?$$

Comment: $$p_{Z\mid X>c}(z)=P(X>c)^{-1}\int_{c}^{\infty}p_{Y}(x^{-1}z)p_{X}(x)x^{-1}dx$$

Comment: Can you please provide a reference?

Comment: A method, rather: the task is to compute $E(u(Z)\mathbf 1_{X>c})$ for every function $u$, and to reach the formula $$E(u(Z)\mathbf 1_{X>c})=P(X>c)\int_\mathbb Ru(z)g(z)dz$$ valid for every measurable bouned function $u$ since then, one can be sure that $g=p_{Z\mid X>c}$. But the LHS is simply $$E(v(X,Y))=\iint v(x,y)p_X(x)p_Y(y)dxdy$$ for some specific function $v$ depending on $u$, hence one can apply the general approach [explained there](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/30966) on a specific case.

Comment: Thanks again Did for your time and great help. I will try to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional pdf is:
$$\begin{align}
f_{XY\mid X>c}(z) & = \frac{\mathrm d \;}{\mathrm d z}\mathsf P(XY\leq z\mid X>c)
\\[1ex] & = \frac{\mathrm d \;}{\mathrm d z}\frac{\mathsf P(XY\leq z, X>c)}{\mathsf P(X>c)}
\\[1ex] & = \frac{\frac{\mathrm d \;}{\mathrm d z}\int_c^\infty\mathsf P(Y\leq z/x)f_X(x)\operatorname d x}{\mathsf P(X>c)}
\\[1ex] & = \frac{\int_c^\infty f_X(x)\frac{\mathrm d \;}{\mathrm d z}\mathsf P(Y\leq z/x)\operatorname d x}{\mathsf P(X>c)}
\\[1ex] & = \frac{\int_c^\infty f_X(x)x^{-1}f_Y(z/x)\operatorname d x}{\mathsf P(X>c)}
\\[1ex] & = \frac{\int_c^\infty x^{-1}\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\lambda z/x}\operatorname d x}{e^{-\lambda c}}
\\[1ex] & = e^{\lambda c}\lambda^2 \int_c^\infty x^{-1} e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\lambda z/x}\operatorname d x
\\[2ex] & \vdots
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks Graham Kemp for your response.