# Random Variables as Sums of Different Random Variables for $R = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to understand the derivation of the PDF of $$R = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$$
I am looking at some derivations and some derivations say that **if** $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then we can say that $$f_{X,Y} = f_X f_Y$$ which is just the law of independence for joint distributions. I don't really understand how we can break up $R$ into $2$ marginals which are both just the marginals of $X$ and $Y$.

For reference, I am trying the simplest example, where $X$ and $Y$ are uniform random variables from $0$ to $1$. I'll attach some of my work just so maybe someone can help me move forward too.

**WORK THUS FAR**

Let $R = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$. Then, $$P(R \leq r) = P(\sqrt{X^2 + Y^2} \leq r) = P(X^2 + Y^2 \leq r^2)$$
Then, we know that the bounds are on the unit circle so we are solving:
$$F_R = \int_{-r}^{r}\int_{-\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}f_{XY}dxdy$$

I'm stuck here.
Thanks.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. uniform in $[0,1]$, then $f_{XY}(x,y)=\mathbf 1((x,y)\in[0,1]^2)$.

Comment: $R(X,Y)$ is a function of vector $(X,Y)$. You need to find the distribution of function of random vector. See. e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7605/distribution-of-functions-of-random-variables and other links about "distribution of function of random vector".

Comment: @P.Quinton Hi, i was just wondering if you could explain how we can get this result intuitively. From my understanding $$f_{XY}(x,y) = f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)$$ independently, which is how we arrive at this. The rest is solving the integral for the bounds. In this attempt, this is sadly wrong, however, that is why we learn.

Comment: Well essentially it is because $f_{XY}=f_X f_Y$ as you mention and both are of the form $\mathbf 1(x\in[0,1])$, now if you multiply them then it is one if and only if both conditions are true which is $\mathbf 1((x,y)\in [0,1]^2)$.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/323617/119261

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now let me suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are valued in $\mathbb{R^+} = (0, \infty)$ and $S \colon = X/Y$.
Then we have
$$
\begin{cases}
X = \frac{RS}{\sqrt{1+S^2}} \\
Y = \frac{R}{\sqrt{1+S^2}} 
\end{cases}
$$

Denote the density of $(X, Y)$ and $(R, S)$ by $f(x, y)$ and $g(r, s)$ respectively.
We can prove (maybe has been proved in the probability course) that
$$
g(r, s) = \left.
f\left( \frac{rs}{\sqrt{1+s^2}}, \frac{r}{\sqrt{1+s^2}} \right) \middle/
\left| 
\begin{pmatrix}
r_x & r_y \\
s_x & s_y
\end{pmatrix}
\right| 
\right.
$$
where $r_x = \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and it is similar to calculate9 $r_y, s_x, s_y$. Inserting into the above equation yields that
$$
g(r, s) = \left.
f\left( \frac{rs}{\sqrt{1+s^2}}, \frac{r}{\sqrt{1+s^2}} \right) \frac{r}{1+s^2}\right.
$$
Then by integrating on $s$ the marginal density $g(r)$ of $R$ is given the following formula.
$$
g(r) = \int_0^\infty \left.
f\left( \frac{rs}{\sqrt{1+s^2}}, \frac{r}{\sqrt{1+s^2}} \right) \frac{r}{1+s^2}
\right.\ ds
$$

If we add the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are indenpent which implies that $f(x, y) = f_X(x) f_y(y)$. Substituting $f$ by $f_Xf_Y$ simplify the formula.
$$
g(r) = \int_0^\infty \left.
f_X\left( \frac{rs}{\sqrt{1+s^2}}\right)f_Y\left(\frac{r}{\sqrt{1+s^2}} \right) \frac{r}{1+s^2}
\right.\ ds
$$
Actually I do think the formula is ugly which makes me suspend that if there is any wrong above.

---

Update: I have veirfied the formula and it should be correct.

For uniform, $f_X(x) = I(0 < x < 1)$ and $f_Y(y) = I(0 < y< 1)$.
Hence
$$
g(r) = \int_0^\infty I\left(0<\frac{rs}{\sqrt{1+s^2}}<1\right) I\left(0<\frac{r}{\sqrt{1+s^2}}<1\right) \frac{r}{1+s^2}\ ds
=\int_D \frac{r}{1+s^2} ds
$$
where $D$ is the joint of $D_1 = \{s: 0<\frac{rs}{\sqrt{1+s^2}}<1\}$ and $D_2 = \{0<\frac{r}{\sqrt{1+s^2}}<1\}$.

Case 1: $0<r<1, D = \mathbb{R}^+, g(r) = \frac\pi2 r$;

Case 2: $1 \le r < \sqrt2, D = (\sqrt{r^2-1}, 1/\sqrt{r^2-1}), g(r) = r(\tan 1/\sqrt{r^2-1} - \tan \sqrt{r^2-1})$;

Case 3: $\sqrt 2 \le r, D = \phi, g(r) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks, i understand the process using the formula you provided. Does this have a name? we haven't covered it yet, however, I am interested and will look into it. Secondly, could you explain a bit on the first line where you define X and Y from S being their quotient? i didn't fully understand this. Thank you!

Comment: Well, I have forgotton that whether the formula has a name but you can see [this note]( https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6630/2015fa/notes/pdf-transform.pdf) for a reference. As for the definition of $S$, actually you can see it as polar transformation like $S^\prime \colon = \arctan X/Y, R = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$ while I use $S = X/Y, R = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$.